# Specific round border of IOS switch

Tags: swift, border, uiswitch

Im trying to specifically get this border color for a switch in IOS :

[image]

But I have tried implementing different answers on this site and these are some of the results :

[image]
[image]
[image]

This is the code I have until now :

```
let createSwitch: () -> UISwitch = {
    let swt = UISwitch()
    swt.layer.cornerRadius = swt.frame.height / 2
    swt.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
    swt.layer.borderWidth = 1
    swt.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return swt
}
```

But although it gets close, it is not exactly what I need.
In the second sample, I almost got it but the border is overlapping the darker background for some reason.

What is wrong here?

Comment: I don't see issues except for the logic of the constant. What is wrong with this code?

Comment: It's best to not try to modify the look of a `UISwitch`. It could change with any iOS update. Might be better to add a view behind the switch to give the look of a border or write a custom switch class that looks just like you want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're familiar with using Cocoapods, I suggest using `PWSwitch`. It is a `UISwitch` implementation that is far more customizable, including things like border color.

I've used it in a number of my projects and its very easy to use.

**Link:** https://github.com/Shaninnik/PWSwitch

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have solved this issue, I ran into the same problem today, but this worked for me : translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true

Answer (score -1):

I just tried running your code and I didn't have any issues.
[image: screenshot]
[image: screenshot]